# How to remove version prefix from request URI and use correct document root?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We need to support few major and minor versions of web-service, so we decide to use version in URL like this:

```
http://service/      # last deployed version of service
http://service/1/    # symlink that points to the last deployed major version 1.x
http://service/1.2/  # symlink that points to the last deployed minor version 1.2.x
```

We store all tags in folders and make symlinks to the correct versions:

```
Here the root directory for apache:
lrwxr-xr-x   1 xxxx xxxx 28 May 23 15:21 1 -> /home/site/tags/20120523084844-HEAD
lrwxr-xr-x   1 xxxx xxxx 28 Apr 27 15:21 1.1 -> /home/site/tags/20120427152123-HEAD
lrwxr-xr-x   1 xxxx xxxx 28 May 23 08:48 1.2 -> /home/site/tags/20120523084844-HEAD
lrwxr-xr-x   1 xxxx xxxx 28 May 24 16:12 2 -> /home/site/tags/20120524161232-HEAD
(source code here for last deployed version)
.....
```

There is a problem here, because we will have version prefix in the REQUEST_URI in PHP and Symfony router won't match it against patterns. How can we cut that version prefix, but still use specific directory as document root?

For example, when we make a request to the `http://service/1.2/some/handler/pattern` then code from 1.2 directory will be used and the REQUEST_URI in PHP will be /some/handler/pattern

Comment: Routing pattern /service/:version/some/handler/pattern (symfony 1) or /service/{version}/some/handler/pattern (symfony 2) doesn't work?

Comment: I do not want to add a version pattern to the source code, because each installation of service shouldn't be aware of version in URI.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^[0-9.]+/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /1.2/$1 [L]
```

The only think is you can only test version at a time, and have to change the htaccess if you want a different one.

Might I suggest using subdomains for the versioning?

Comment: Thank you for an answer! Unfortunately, we need to support multiple versions at a time. I have already thought about virtual subdomains and transparent reverse-proxying with apache. But this will be too complicated to use in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem.

I don't think it can be done with htaccess only, at least not without ugly hacks. REQUEST_URI always holds the original request, and as far as I know there's no way to edit that (if we try to assign content to the variable REQUEST_URI via E=REQUEST_URI="something", then an environmental variable called "REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI" will be created).

I'm not familiar with Symfony, so I don't know how easy it is to edit the script that handles the routing. If it's easy, you could do something like

```
RewriteRule ^[1-9.]/(.*)$ - [R,QSA,NC,E=HANDLER:$1]
```

then in the PHP you could copy the handler to the request_uri:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HANDLER'];
```

Aside changing the PHP like this, I can only think of this: first hard-redirect to the handler, putting the version info in the query string. Then catch that request, and soft-redirect to version/handler. The Request_uri will be set correctly, but it's ugly and very much error-prone.

That said, I totally agree with Gerben about using subdomains for versioning.

Comment: Yes, it seems there is no elegant solution. Only subdomains with proxying. It's pity, but I'll put a hack at the code level (